# List of exemplary questions on AI theory

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

The purpose of this post is to compile lists of exemplary question that can be used to promote SE:AI to the wider AI research and engineering community on the internet.

Stack provides a unique setting for exchange of specific, technical information at a large scale, and in this way is distinct among top social sites. (This is validated in the way adding math formatting allowed the stack to blossom, and has yielded a large number of exemplary answers.)

As an example, hare are some of my favorites:

[What does the symbol $\mathbb E$ mean in these equations?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/14159/1671)

[What is the relation between Q-learning and policy gradients methods?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/6196/1671)

[Why is A* optimal if the heuristic function is admissible?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/6026/1671)

For philosophical questions, this recent query has proven fertile ground for a range of valid answers:

[Can digital computers understand infinity?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/15730/1671)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a non-exhaustive list of my favorite questions and answers, which does not mean they are perfect or cannot be improved.

### Questions

- [Can neural networks be used to prove conjectures?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/7416/2444)

#### Questions to which I gave an answer

- [Why do we need common sense in AI?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/13261/2444)
- [Are neural networks prone to catastrophic forgetting?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/13289/2444)
- [What sort of mathematical problems are there in AI that people are working on?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/12971/2444)
- [What is the relevance of AIXI on current artificial intelligence research?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/145/2444)
- [Why is dropout favoured compared to reducing the number of units in hidden layers?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/17044/2444)
- [How can supervised learning be viewed as a conditional probability of the labels given the inputs?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/17670/2444)

#### My questions

- [Why doesn't Q-learning converge when using function approximation?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/11679/2444)
- [Why is the equation $\mathbb{E} \left[ (Y - \hat{Y})^2 \right] = \left(f(X) - \hat{f}(X) \right)^2 + \operatorname{Var} (\epsilon)$ true?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/27830/2444)
- [Why was the VC dimension not defined for all configurations of $d$ points?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/27854/2444)
- [Why does a negative reward for every step really encourage the agent to reach the goal as quickly as possible?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/24375/2444)

### Answers

- [What is the Bellman operator in reinforcement learning?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/11133/2444) (with mathematical details)
- [Why is a softmax used rather than dividing each activation by the sum?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/17328/2444) (with mathematical details)
- [Why do we need explainable AI?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/14247/2444)

#### My answers

- [How can we find the value function by solving a system of linear equations?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/28566/2444) (with mathematical details; topic: RL)
- [How to estimate the capacity of a neural network?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/17881/2444) (with mathematical details; topic: learning theory)
- [What is the difference between First-Visit Monte-Carlo and Every-Visit Monte-Carlo Policy Evaluation?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/10818/2444) (with mathematical details; topic: RL)
- [How is iterative deepening A* better than A*?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/8909/2444) (with mathematical details; topic: search)
- [Why is the equation $\mathbb{E} \left[ (Y - \hat{Y})^2 \right] = \left(f(X) - \hat{f}(X) \right)^2 + \operatorname{Var} (\epsilon)$ true?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/27831/2444) (with mathematical details; topic: ML)
- [Do convolutional neural networks perform convolution or cross-correlation?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/22000/2444) (with mathematical details; topic: CNNs)
- [What is the relevance of AIXI on current artificial intelligence research?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/10377/2444) (topic: AGI/AIXI)
- [Are neural networks prone to catastrophic forgetting?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/13293/2444) (topic: neural networks)
- [What is self-supervised learning in machine learning?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/10624/2444) (topic: ML)
- [What is artificial intelligence?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/11387/2444)  (topic: AI field)

Of course, I am biased towards questions and answers where I am involved, but this does not mean that there aren't many other good questions and answers on this site.

Comment: Thanks for doing it!