# Can we arrange a call to past active users?

Tags: discussion

Since there are at-least few users on this site who are active in past and are absolutely silent now.

Can we ping them in chats or in comments or some way to let them know that we need their contribution again like past? Is it a good practice to do so or are we disturbing them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know if someone has done that in the past or not, but I don't think it's a very good idea. These users probably don't contribute to the site anymore because they don't have the time or desire to do it. Most, if not all, of them are volunteers, like you and me, so we should not bother them with these requests.

It seems to me that a user usually remains because he likes the idea of helping others and maybe also learning something by reading other people's answers/questions and, in the meantime, he/she also finds the time to do it. I've stayed around because I thought that this community could be useful and I like to help others whenever I can, so not because someone asked me to do it.

Answer (score 1):

My sense is that interest waxes and wanes over the course of years.  Sometimes the user becomes re-inspired and comes back, sometimes not.

I have multiple stacks where I either have high current participation, or don't have time/inclination to think about.  This usually ping pongs with my core areas of interest.

But you're on the right track that what we need to do is attract more qualified and earnest users.  My suggestion:

- **Post the Q&As you find most rewarding on social media**

Encourage others to do this.

I'm not sure the wider AI community realizes what a great and reliable resource is Stack:AI.  And I've looked at the quality of AI information on less rigorous forums and Q&A, such that, with certain exceptions cases, I stick to stack.

See also: [List of exemplary questions on AI theory](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1627/list-of-exemplary-questions-on-ai-theory)